# Angular 8 ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I have **ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null** on *npm run build prod --aot=true* in my Angular 8 project. The local build works perfect.

I found, that this error appears when I'm trying to convert some object to Route by a special function, and after that add this route to Routes array.

Please help to understand how to fix it.

Some piece of code:

```
function objToRoute(obj: any): Route {
   // convert it to route and return
}

const routes: Routes = [
   path: '',
   component: SomeComponent,
   children: [
      objToRoute(specialObject),
      {
                path: '**',
                component: StubComponent
      }
   ]
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SomeRoutingModule {}
```

To be more specific, here is a simple example of objToRoute function:

```
function objToRoute(obj: any): Route {
   return obj;
}

const routeObj: Route = {
    path: 'somePath',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () => import('pathToDir/someLazy.module').then(m => m.SomeLazyModule)
}

const routes: Routes = [
   path: '',
   component: SomeComponent,
   children: [
      objToRoute(routeObj),
      {
                path: '**',
                component: StubComponent
      }
   ]
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SomeRoutingModule {}
```

And in this case I have the error **ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined** on *npm run build prod --aot=true*

Comment: Moreover, if function takes Route object and return this object (untouched), error appears again (

Comment: How about showing us the `objToRoute` function, so that we can actually help you?

Comment: Problem seems to come from `objToRoute`. Please add it to your question for help 

Comment: @MartinChoraine Yes, added a simple example.

Comment: I guess that your import path is relative ? Can you try to make it absolute ? `src/app/...`